# inline overload throwing errors c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, overloading, inline

I am learning overloading an inline function.

In testing this code I can't compile with the following errors I can't understand as to what's wrong.

I tested it with only 1 inline function and works but a second breaks it. Can you please share some guidance:

Thank you for your help, Sergio

Compiler errors:

- abs exception specification does not match previous declaration line 13
- function long abs (const long) throw() already has body line 13
- abs redefinition; different exception specification line 19
- abs error in function definition or declaration; function not called line 30
- abs error in function definition or declaration; function not called line 32

---

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Overload abs() three ways
inline int abs(int n)
{
    cout << "In integer abs() \n";
    return((n < 0) ? -n : n);
}

inline long abs(long n)
{
    cout << "In long abs() \n";
    return((n < 0) ? -n : n);
}


inline double abs(double n) {
    cout << "In double abs() \n";
    return ((n < 0 ? -n : n));
}


int main()
{
    cout << "Absolute value of -10 Is ";
    cout << abs(-10) << "\n";
    cout << "Absolute value of -10L Is ";
    cout << abs(-10L) << "\n";
    cout << "Absolute value of -10.01 Is ";
    cout << abs(-10.01) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Get rid of the `using namespace std;`.

Answer (score 5):

Your error is here:

```
using namespace std;
```

since this brings into the global namespace the definitions of the function overloads `std::abs()` (they are declared & defined in `cmath` which appears to be `#include`d directly or indirectly into `iostream`), which then clash with your own definitions. The above statement (`using namespace std;`) is almost never a good idea, certainly not in a header file -- it is, unfortunately, commonly used in online coding contests to simplify code (no need for `std::`).

Btw, this has only do with `inline` inasmuch as the function definitions (not the declarations) clash, which must be declared `inline` in header files to obtain the proper linkage.

Answer (score 3):

Precense of `using namespace std;` causes a conflict with `::std::abs` function. However getting rid of `using namespace std;` will not solve the issue complitely.

The primary problem here is the use of a non-unique name for a function in `global` namespace. `abs` is a function from C standard library therefore you should not use this name for your own functions. Otherwise your may get an error if `<stdlib.h>` is included somewhere, or even a random Undefined Behavior because of ODR violation.

In order to prevent name conflicts in C++ you should typically define new functions in custom namespace:

```
n_sergio_solorzano_stuff
{
    // Overload abs() three ways
    inline int abs(int n)
    {
    ...
```

or select globally unique names when you need to add something into global namespace:

```
inline int sergio_solorzano_stuff_abs(int n)
```